# Getting username,password from UIAlertview to use in willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge xcode

Tags: authentication, uialertview

I am trying to get username and password from uialertview and pass to  willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge. These are my code.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",@"Auto", nil];

alertView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.75);
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
[alertView show];


if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside challenge previousFailureCount==0");
        NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                       credentialWithUser:Username
                                       password:Password
                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];


        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
//Index1 = OK
//Index2 = Auto
//Index0 = Cancel

NSLog(@"Alert View dismissed with button at index %d",buttonIndex);

if(buttonIndex==1)
{
    NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge;
    Username= [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

    Password= [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;

}
}
```

The problem is I can't call username and password from UIalertview to pass.If I write above code, before the user write username and password, it will do challenge. We have to wait till user press OK. Moreover, if I do challenge in didDismissWithButtonIndex, I also got error. 
I would like to know how to do.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

while clicking on alertView button it dismiss alertView .Better take on more alertView and pass your value there.

If this is not the senario i would recommend please elaborate what you exactly want.

Comment: Thanks bro. I have found a way to do.

Answer (score 0):

oh....I think I found out a way to do. I can recall willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge.So, at first, UIalertview will display. We will save username and password. Then, we recall willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge and pass username and password.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    //Index1 = OK
    //Index2 = Auto
    //Index0 = Cancel
    checkUserPw=TRUE;
    checkTochangeUIalert=FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Alert View dismissed with button at index %d",buttonIndex);

    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        checkManualAuthentication=TRUE; 
        NSLog(@"User clicks OK");
        self.UserName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

        self.Password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;

        connection_for_auto = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:toRedirectURL] delegate:self];

        [connection_for_auto start];

    }
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

if(!checkUserPw){
    //so that alert will display only once.
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",@"Auto", nil];

    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
       NSURLCredential *credentail =nil;
       credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                       credentialWithUser:self.UserName
                                       password:self.Password
                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
  [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```